# "Proportion of IPOs in France"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Assume you read a text discussing the total value of all [IPOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_public_offering) world-wide and those in France, stating France's IPOs' total value is 9% of those world-wide. Is it valid to refer to this percentage as "proportion of IPOs in France"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, though I am not an expert in finance. For me, "the proportion of IPOs in France" may very well refer to the total number of IPOs instead of their total value. I think you need a longer phrase for clarity, such as "the share of France in the total value of IPOs world wide". Perhaps a shorter phrase can be found.

[Edit] What about: "the French share in global IPO value"?

Comment: What about "the proportion (by value) of IPOs in France", possibly augmented with "compared to the worldwide total"?

Comment: @Jonathan: It might work in context. Without context, it sounds a bit odd to me. I'd expect something like "the proportion (by value) of IPOs in France that can be considered a success is about 30%". I think part of the problem is in the link between "IPOs" and "in France": the limitation "in France" is supposed to be applied to "the proportion", but, because it comes after "IPOs", it is applied to "IPOs", which is not right. If this link goes wrong, the opposition France-world is not clear.